# 2008 Volvo Bushings & Sway arms rattling

Tags: suspension

On May 6, 2016, Volvo recommended Replacing:

both Control Arms due to Front & Rear Bushings torn/broken;

both Sway Bars which are worn out & rattling.

I didn't have work done. Now, when I break I hear Scraping and some kind of Thumping (Though the breaking system was judged to have "performed normally during road test.")

Is this dangerous when driving?

Comment: Is it dangerous to drive a car that is scraping and thumping when you brake? I think you know the answer to this...

Answer (score 1):

"Scraping and some kind of Thumping" could indicate worn out pads/rotors, as well.

Regardless, there are known problems with your steering and possibly braking components - yes, it's dangerous. It will probably still get you around for a while, but maintenance needs to be performed on-time or you will cause further damage (uneven tire wear, ball joints, etc.). You won't save money by putting off these repairs.